How does Bharatiya Anthariksh Station differ from ISS
Why does India develop the Bhartiya Anthariksh Station when the International Space Station is already active?
What is the significance of the BAS?
Will India partake in future missions like the ISS?

Did you look at when the ISS is going to be splashed?

Why does anyone want a car when there is public transit?

@user3528438 - Many years ago I lived within walking distance of a bus stop, and the same bus went past my workplace, so I thought great I’ll ride the bus to work. It was miserable, it took so much longer. Not so much all of the stops, which by itself slowed things down, but also the bus schedule never aligned with my work schedule. But I made myself ride it once a week. More than once I would be at work and someone would say “After work we are going to such-and-such” and I suddenly remembered I didn’t have my car because it was “bus day”.

@user3528438 Because they can't afford a car. See Space Station Freedom.


Will India partake in future missions like ISS?

News article (article is updated on July 30, 2024)

One of the four astronauts undergoing training for the Gaganyaan mission will travel to the International Space Station as part of a collaborative effort with National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA), ...


... NASA has identified a private entity Axiom Space and ISRO had signed a Space Flight Agreement with the American firm for the joint mission to the International Space Station (ISS).

News article 2 (article updated on Sep 9, 2024)

two of the four astronaut-designates has commenced training with Axiom Space for the upcoming Ax-4 mission to the International Space Station (ISS).


not a full answer; addresses only the third question.

“collaborative effort” with NASA and “joint mission” as stated in the article is quite a stretch. Axiom Space facilitates paid tourist flights to ISS. They refer to it as commercial space flights, but either way the participants pay SpaceX many millions of dollars to launch them to ISS for a few days, and they pay NASA millions of dollars basically for food and oxygen and some other services. The more significant achievement will be India’s own space capsule which Indian astronauts are currently training to fly on. ISRO astronauts flying to ISS on Axiom flights is not nearly as big of a deal.
